# System-wide x11vnc for GDM on 20.04

Tags: login, xorg, remote-desktop, vnc, gdm

I'm trying to setup system-wide x11vnc so even if no users are logged in, I can remotely connect and start a Gnome session.  I followed this tutorial on the Arch Linux wiki as it seemed to mirror fairly closely what I need to achieve:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x11vnc#Run_x11vnc_%22system-wide%22_in_(GDM_and_GNOME_Shell)

The service works and I can connect to my VNC server on the default port 5900, however I just see the "Ubuntu" logo at the bottom of the screen just like before the display manager boots up:

TightVNC Screenshot
[image]
I've tried setting WaylandEnable=false in the GDM conf but it doesn't seem to help.

Is there anything I need to do to be able to tap into the display manager?  Here are my systemd service definitions:

Thanks!

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc server for GDM
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -many -shared -display :0 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -noxdamage -rfbauth /home/mattias/.vnc/passwd
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc server for Gnome shell session of mattias

[Service]
User=mattias
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'while ! pgrep -U "mattias" Xorg; do sleep 2; done'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'sudo systemctl stop x11vnc-gdm.service && /usr/bin/x11vnc -many -shared -display :0 -auth /home/mattias/.Xauthority -rfbauth /home/mattias/.vnc/passwd'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```